# EAS build android keeps failing

Tags: android, reactjs, expo, eas

I am trying to build an APK for past few days using ‘eas build’. But facing issues which i am not able to resolve through any means. That’s why came to this forum with hope of a resolution.

My project worked fine on emulators / android devices through expo go
I have successfully created apk for this project through expo build
In the same project, I just changed login for returning users using async storage.
Now I am getting errors while creating an APK for my project.

**App.json**

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "TOFI_App",
    "slug": "TOFI_Tagging",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/white-icon1.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/tofiscreen.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/ec0fed5d-1c13-4504-a075-88036d1de361"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "IOSBuild",
      "runtimeVersion": {
        "policy": "sdkVersion"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
        
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
      ],
      "package": "com.gopalkrishna.TOFI_Tagging",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqkgGo2V1iJUVBgz8A"
        }
      },
      "runtimeVersion": {
        "policy": "sdkVersion"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "cameraPermission": "To click field photos, this app needs access of your mobile's camera."
        }
      ],
      "expo-build-properties"
    ],
    "extra": {
      "firebase": {
        "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "authDomain": "tofi-imageupload.firebaseapp.com",
        "databaseURL": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.app",
        "projectId": "tofi-xxxxxxxx",
        "storageBucket": "tofi-xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
        "messagingSenderId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "appId": "1:xxxxxxxxxxx:web:ec5dbdexxxxxxxxxxxxxx0",
        "measurementId": "G-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx75-88036d1de361"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "tofi_tagging",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dev-event/react-native-maps-draw": "^2.0.0",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.0",
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.1.48",
    "@expo/ngrok": "^2.5.0",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^12.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^12.3.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "@sideway/pinpoint": "^2.0.0",
    "@siposdani87/expo-maps-polygon-editor": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.8",
    "core-js": "^3.24.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.6.0",
    "expo-camera": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-cli": "^6.3.2",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.2.1",
    "expo-dev-menu": "^2.2.0",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-firebase-core": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-sqlite": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "fiction-expo-restart": "^1.0.5",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "modules": "^0.4.0",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "ngrok": "^4.3.3",
    "node": "^16.17.0",
    "npm": "^8.19.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^1.0.18",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.0.1-rc.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.70.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-material-design": "^0.3.5",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-really-awesome-button": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.24",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "watchman": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@expo/ngrok": "^4.1.0",
    "metro": "^0.72.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**eas.json**

```js
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 1.0.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      },
      "channel": "development"
    },
    "preview": {
      "extends": "production",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel": "preview"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "channel": "production"
    }
  }
}
```

***error in eas build dashboard***
[image]

any help to build the apk will be highly appreciated. thanks!